# seticon() in tab layout crashes in prelollipop

Tags: android, vector, android-tablayout

I am getting  android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: error in prelollipop devices. Below is my code snippet. I am using vector icons. How to resolve this? I dont want to use png's of the icon.

```
TabLayout.Tab tabCall1 = tabLayout.getTabAt(0);
tabCall1.setIcon(R.drawable.tab1_selector);


<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_rss_symbol_black" android:state_selected="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_rss_symbol" android:state_selected="false" />

</selector>`
```

EDIT1: i tried wrapping drawables in layerlist but still it didnt work
EDIT2: i remove selector and simply set a layerlist in seticon() still it crashes

Comment: have you enabled support for vectordrawable in your gradle.file?

Comment: yes.. they(vectors) are working fine everywhere

Comment: vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

Comment: Which version of support library are you using?

Comment: 25.3.1 support version

Comment: Have you called `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);` in your Application or Activity?

Comment: yes i have put static{ App.... } in application class

Comment: Your TabLayout in XML is coming from the support library `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout` right?

Comment: yes sir i m using support version android.support.design.widget.TabLayout

Comment: Your `TabLayout.Tab` in code is coming from support library package too? PS: You should remove `android:state_selected="false"` from XML selector because this is the default value

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```
tabCall1.setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(your_context, R.drawable.tab1_selector));
```

Comment: same error Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/tab1_selector.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020169